# What is the proper way to apply s command to an object?

Tags: vim, vi

For example, I often use the substitute command on all the lines in a block or a paragraph.  I have an idiom that works for me:

```
   !ip<bs>s/foo/bar/
```

but every time I do it that way, I get this feeling that I do not grok the language of VI.  I can do other operations on objects, like

```
   dip  or  yip  or cip
```

but not sip.   It does not fit into the vi/vim language as I understand it.  So, I do !ip, then erase the '!', then proceed to type in my s/// command.  That is the shortest, least unnatural way of expressing that operation that I know of.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I understand your point, but I believe there is no better way using the default commands. There is an alternative when you have the `+visual` feature available:

```
vip:s/foo/bar/
```

But it has the same key count and no advantage.
If you are open to customization, you could create a new command to do what you are expecting. For example, you could type `sip` and have the cursor at the command line with the selected range and `s/`, as described in [`:help :map-operator`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3amap%2doperator). For example:

```
nnoremap s :set opfunc=SubstituteOperator<CR>g@

function! SubstituteOperator(type, ...)
   silent call feedkeys(":'[,']:s/", 'n')
endfunction
```

Comment: I'd agree that the `vip...` approach is probably more in line with the "vim language" OP describes.